# Bluebird catch err logging syntax?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, mongoose, promise, bluebird

What is the equivalent Bluebird promise err logging to this:

```
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
    }
```

For this:

```
}).catch(Promise.OperationalError, function(e){
    // handle error in Mongoose save findOne etc, res.send(...)
}).catch(function(e){
    // handle other exceptions here, this is most likely
    // a 500 error where the top one is a 4XX, but pay close
    // attention to how you handle errors here
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluebird will automatically log unhandled rejections for you. If you wish to send a server response on an error and mark the chain as handled you can do:

```
.catch(function(err){
     console.log(err);
     res.send(err);
     throw err; // this is optional, if you don't want to mark the chain as handled.
 });
```

Comment: i was excatly looking on how to continue the error chain to handle logging in a separate block. thanks!